# Bar mitzvah for child born in Adar

Tags: bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, adar

If a child is born in Adar of a non-leap year, and he/she reaches the age of 13/12 in a leap year, when is it appropriate to celebrate the child becoming bar/bat mitzvah?  Would that be Adar I or Adar II?

Comment: Hi Harold. Did you try googling this question before asking here? What did you find lacking or confusing that you seek clarification? Please edit your post to clarify

Answer (score 2):

> **A boy born in the month of Adar of a non-leap year celebrates his bar
> mitzvah in the second Adar, if his bar mitzvah year is a leap year.** *(Rama on Code of Jewish Law, Orach Chaim 55:10)*
> Nevertheless, there are some halachic authorities that maintain that
> the bar mitzvah should be celebrated in the first Adar. In order to
> satisfy this opinion, the boy should put on tefillin starting from the
> date of his birthday in the first Adar. *(Shevet Halevi 6:9.)*
>
> [Source](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1048736/jewish/The-Laws-of-Bar-Mitzvah.htm)

The same applies to Bat Mitva. It's  celebrated on the second adar.

Comment: So doe _kulei alma_ agree with the Rema there? Perhaps Sephardim do differently? By the way, this was really interesting and unexpected. +1

Comment: Very nice article: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pw9x9ubrw8fj7gm/Purim_To_Go_-_5771_Rabbi_Willig.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @ezra `So doe _kulei alma_ agree with the Rema there? Perhaps Sephardim do differently?` great point. I'll try to search that up. It does say in the article that i posted, that there are those who disagree with the rama, and therefore the shevet levi says to start with tefilin on adar alef

Comment: I checked the _Rama_ and see nothing about celebrating. It only says when the boy becomes a _bar mitzva_.

Comment: @msh210 are you taking about the text i quoted? I didn't write it up, but it's obvious to me, celebre=become bar mitzva. I mean there is no halachic time to "celebrate" your bar mitzva